# How to do `$text` search on one collection to get the data from the other collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to provide search for e-commerce site. In that there is a 4-level menu like this `category>>subcategory>>product>>subproduct`. I had divided them into 3 schemas like this

category schema

```
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    "catname": {type: String, required: true},
}
);
mongoose.model('category',categorySchema);
```

subcategory and product schema

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    "catid": {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'category'},
    "subcatname": {type: String, required: true},
    "product":[
        {
            "productname":{type:String},
        }
    ]
}
);
mongoose.model('product',productSchema);
```

subproduct schema

```
var subproductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    "productid": {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'products', required: true},
    "itemcode": {type: String, required: true},
    "itemname": {type: String, required: true/*, index: "text"*/},
    "itemdescription": {type: String, required: true},
    "itemimgurl": {type: String, required: true},
    "mainprice": {type: Number},
    "offerprice": {type: Number, required: true},
    "unit": {type: String, required: true},
    "stock": {type: Number, required: true},
    "offertag": {type: String},
    "itemprice":[
        {
            "itemname" :{type: String, required: true},
            "unit": {type: String, required: true},
            "offerprice": {type: Number, required: true},
            "mainprice": {type: Number},
            "stock": {type: Number, required: true},
            "notify": {type: Number, required: true},
            "status": {type: Boolean, required: true},
            "itemimgurl": {type: String},
            "offertag": {type: String}
        }
    ]
}
);
mongoose.model('subproduct',subproductSchema);
```

I need to give the `subproducts` corresponding to the users search, like if the user searches with the `catname` or `subcatname` or `productname` or `itemname` need to give the related `subproducts`. How can I achieve this with mongoose?

Comment: In order to do what you are trying to accomplish, you should make a mapping between all the modules. **MongoDb** query can only run for a single collection at a time so you can store the name of your `catname, subcatname, productname and itemname` into your schema of `subproducts` or make seperate schema making an object for each mapping.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik, Thanks for the idea of storing `catname`, `subcatname`, `productname` into `subproducts` schema. I achieved it. Thanks alot.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik, I need one more help. Can you please tell me how to create compound index in `subproduct` schema using mongoose.

Comment: And is there any possibility to search for an incomplete word or a single character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is with reference to the question you asked in the comment.

If you want to search for an incomplete query or a word, i will provide a small code, which will help you.

```
var query = req.body.query;  //the string you take for search
var filter = {
        $or: [
                {subcatname: new RegExp('.*' + query, 'i')},
                {productname: new RegExp('.*' + query, 'i')},
                //similarly you can put more cases
            ]
    }

subproducts.find(filter, function(err, data){
       if(err){console.log(err);}
       console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: If we want to search for number field, how to query it?